# GPT partition type for ext4 filesystem

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, mount, gdisk

My disk is formatted using GPT. I created a new partition and by default it was create as 'Linux filesystem' (gdisk code 8300).

When I am trying to mount it via fstab

```
/dev/sda4 /vmguests               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

it errors out with

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4
```

What would be the right type code for ext4 filesystem in gdisk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error message has nothing to do with GPT (or MBR) type codes; it's referring to the *filesystem* contained *within* the partition. I suspect you haven't created that filesystem. Many partitioning tools, including `gdisk`, do not create filesystems; they just create the partitions in which filesystems can be created. To create a filesystem, you'd need to use a command like this:

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda4
```

You must type that command as `root` or via the `sudo` utility, just like `gdisk`.

Some tools, such as GParted, do both jobs simultaneously, which is convenient but muddies the waters a bit for those learning the system, because it's easy to misunderstand the distinction between partitions and filesystems. Partitions are simple data structures that consist of the starting sector number and the ending sector number (or, equivalently, the length), as well as associated meta-data such as a type code. Filesystems are much more complex data structures that are typically contained within a partition. Filesystems facilitate the creation and manipulation of files -- often thousands of them.

Incidentally, the Linux kernel ignores partition type codes. So do many Linux utilities. Linux partitioning tools support them because they're part of partition table data structures and because some other OSes use type codes as a filter, so it's important that the Linux codes be right in a dual-boot environment. Linux installation programs also often use type codes in a similar way.

Comment: Well what would be the correct partition type code for ext4 then?

Comment: The correct GPT type code for Linux filesystems is 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4. This is reduced to the code "8300" in GPT fdisk, but that's a semi-arbitrary mapping that's not used by most other tools. GNU Parted, for instance, doesn't present type codes per se; instead, it reports on what filesystem is used within the partition. (GNU Parted does set the type code correctly when you tell it to create a Linux filesystem, though.) Other tools may do other things.